# Call a function from c++ via environment Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I am considering calling a R function from c++ via environment, but I got an error, here is what I did

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;



// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector call(NumericVector x){
  Environment env = Environment::global_env();
  Function f = env["fivenum"];
  NumericVector res = f(x);
  return res;
}
```

Type `call(x)`, this is what I got,

```
Error: cannot convert to function
```

I know I can do it right in another way,

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector callFunction(NumericVector x, Function f) {
    NumericVector res = f(x);
    return res;
}
```

and type

```
callFunction(x,fivenum)
```

But still wondering why first method failed.

Comment: fivenum function is not defined in the global environment but in the stats package... not sure but this should work: `Environment stats("package:stats");
  Function f = stats["fivenum"];`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`fivenum`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/fivenum.html) function is not defined in the global environment but in the `stats` package enviroment, so you should get it from that:

```
...
Environment stats("package:stats"); 
Function f = stats["fivenum"];
...
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @digEmAll's answer, I would like to mention a more general approach, which mimics R's packagename::packagefunctionX(...) approach.
The advantage is that you don't have to call library("dependend_library"), i.e., in this case, library(stats). That is useful when you call a function from your package, without previously calling library.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector five_nums(Rcpp::NumericVector x){
  Rcpp::Environment stats = Rcpp::Environment::namespace_env("stats");
  Rcpp::Function f = stats["fivenum"];
  return Rcpp::NumericVector(f(x));
}

/*** R
 five_nums(stats::rnorm(25, 2, 3))
*/
```