# Call R functions in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I was trying to call the sd(x), which is a R function, in Rcpp. I've seen an example of calling the R function dbate(x) in Rcpp and it works perfectly.

```
// dens calls the pdf of beta distribution in R
//[[Rcpp::export]]
double dens(double x, double a, double b)
{
    return R::dbeta(x,a,b,false);
}
```

But when I tired to apply this method to sd(x) as following, it went wrong.

```
// std calls the sd function in R
//[[Rcpp::export]]
double std(NumericVector x)
{
  return R::sd(x);
}
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Comment: Can you provide the error message ?

Comment: Yes! It has several error messages:
redefinition of 'std' as a different kind of symbol;
no member named 'sd' in namespace 'R'; did you mean simply 'sd'?
unexpected namespace 'std': expected expression

Comment: Anyway, this approach should work --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594628/call-a-function-from-c-via-environment-rcpp

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I can learn another way to make this work!

Answer (score 16):

There are a few issues with your code.

1. `std` is related to the [C++ Standard Library namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library)

   - This is triggering:

     > error: redefinition of 'std' as different kind of symbol
2. The `R::` is a namespace that deals with [Rmath functions](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/82d8a3a922fc158f2403b233b2ac6861c538d514/inst/include/Rcpp/Rmath.h). Other `R` functions will **not** be found in within this scope.
3. To directly call an R function from within C++ you must use `Rcpp::Environment` and `Rcpp::Function` as given in the example `sd_r_cpp_call()`.

   - There are many issues with this approach though including but not limited to the loss of speed.
4. It is ideal to use [Rcpp sugar](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-sugar.pdf) expressions or implement your own method.

With this being said, let's talk code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

//' @title Accessing R's sd function from Rcpp
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double sd_r_cpp_call(const Rcpp::NumericVector& x){

  // Obtain environment containing function
  Rcpp::Environment base("package:stats"); 

  // Make function callable from C++
  Rcpp::Function sd_r = base["sd"];    

  // Call the function and receive its list output
  Rcpp::NumericVector res = sd_r(Rcpp::_["x"] = x,
                                 Rcpp::_["na.rm"]  = true); // example of additional param

  // Return test object in list structure
  return res[0];
}


// std calls the sd function in R
//[[Rcpp::export]]
double sd_sugar(const Rcpp::NumericVector& x){
  return Rcpp::sd(x); // uses Rcpp sugar
}

/***R
x = 1:5
r = sd(x)
v1 = sd_r_cpp_call(x)
v2 = sd_sugar(x)

all.equal(r,v1)
all.equal(r,v2)
*/
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return R::sd(x); // uses Rcpp sugar` ?

Comment: No. This function is part of Rcpp sugar and not the Rmath library.